# Sending Binary and Textdata via HTTP POST

Tags: java, http, streamwriter

I try to use HTTP POST to send some Data to a Server.
The Server expects the binary Data in $_POST['file'].

```
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream =  connection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write("file=".getBytes());

                //byte[] buffer contains the data
            outputStream.write(buffer);         
        outputStream.close();
```

Is OutputStream.write the right method to write into the stream? Do I have to handle the string ("file=") other then the buffer?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend converting your data to Base64 String (Compatibility with all systems).

```
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to write text with `POST`, you will need to write to `OutputStream.

For parameters, you will need to create a String of key-value pair (separated with `&`) and write the byte array of that data in `OutputStream` as follows:

```
String parameterString = "file=" + parameters.get("file") + "&" + "other=" + parameter.get("other");
outputStream.write(parameterString.getBytes("UTF-8"); //Don't forget, HTTP protocol supports UTF-8 encoding.
outputStream.flush();
```

---

To do file upload with `URLConnection`, see BalusC's article [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: The problem is, that i have to send the concent of a binary file. I don't think that I can just add it to "file=", can I?